# Why isn't my SVG being created?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

My code looks like this:

Index.html

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Fuel_Plan.js"></script>
    <div class="mydiv">
    </div>   

</body>
```

Fuel_Plan.js:

```
var width = 800;
var height = 300;


var svg = d3.select(".mydiv")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width )
    .attr("height", height );
```

What am I trying to achieve? Draw a blank SVG (and append a background image to it, but that is for later!)
So I select "mydiv" and i append an SVG to it, then I give it attrs, of width and height.

When I go into my browser though, I am seeing this:

[image: An image of my browser with the inspected element of the div]

As you can see it's not correctly displaying the SVG, can someone help me what I'm doing wrong here? I'm sure i'm missing something basic!

**Console is empty**

Comment: Your `svg` is not even appended - I guess that is the main problem

Comment: Your problem here is very simple: at the moment the script runs, there is no div. Move the script to the bottom of the body.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I moved my script insert, to the bottom of my div and it still doesn't work, should I update my post?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado if you copy my answer ill accept it as  you were the one who gave it just in the comments :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="mydiv">
</div>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="Fuel_Plan.js"></script>
```

above will work, script was running before div was created.